# Zend Based REST URI for POST and PUT methods

Tags: zend-framework, rest, post

This post if a follow-up question to mt previous post:

[Android RESTful Web application using Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881848/android-mobile-web-application-using-zend-framework)

I have written a web application which is based on the Zend Framework (Version 1.11.11) and I want to use the SAME backend code for coding the mobile version of this application (Android). To achieve this, I want to get the response for each of the actions in the controllers in XML and JSON - for mobile-based app.

Using the answers provided in the above link, I am able to get the XML and JSON response by making use of the AjaxContext helper. I set the contexts as json for the required actions in the init method and I am getting the desired json response.

Now I have another challenge. How to know from the URL if the given action was a GET or a POST request? Do I have have to add that as a query parameter? Is that the correct way?

For example, for login action within User controller: URL will be: [link] (http://localhost/user/login)
But within the loginAction, I check if the given request if a post and authenticate only if the request is a post. So the URL: http://localhost/user/login?format=xml will always return to me the response for a GET request since there is no way of knowing if the request was a GET or POST. Please help.

Thanks.
Abhilash

Comment: You don't need to write another question, I've edited my answer in your previous question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881848/android-mobile-web-application-using-zend-framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like you added format parameter do the same for request . Use "method" parameter to decide what type of request is it . Or you can also do is

```
 $this->getRequest()->isPost(); //create
$this->getRequest()->isGet();   //read
$this->getRequest()->isPut();   // update
$this->getRequest()->isDelete();  // delete
```